# GraphDiameter for molecule graphs error

Tags: graphs-and-networks, chemistry

I was looking into GraphDiameter for molecules and ended up on this [page][1], which gives examples in various modalities to calculate the graph diameter for this molecule.'CC(C)C(C(=O)NC(=O)C1CCCN1C(=O)C(C)NC(=O)C(C)NC(=O)CCC(=O)OC)NC2=CC=C(C=C2)N+[O-]', with PubChem CID 5487286. The reported graph diameter is 24.

However, when I try the same molecule in Mathematica, the graph diameter is reported as 25.

```
mx = Molecule[ExternalIdentifier["PubChemCompoundID", 5487286]];
GraphDiameter[MoleculeGraph[mx]]
%Out = 25
```

The same result is reported if SMILES string is used to create the molecule.

```
GraphDiameter[MoleculeGraph[Molecule["CC(C)C(C(=O)NC(=O)C1CCCN1C(=O)C(C)NC(=O)C(C)NC(=O)CCC(=O)OC)NC2=CC=C(C=C2)[N+](=O)[O-]"]]]
```

I wonder if this is a bug and if there's a workaround.

Thank you,

[1] https://ctr.fandom.com/wiki/Find_the_graph_diameter

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions, as stated in the tag description. This is not a bug, just a difference in what the article described and what you are doing. The article does not consider hydrogen atoms, and states this at the beginning. `MoleculeGraph` does. Voting to close as "simple mistake".

Comment: I apologize for using the bugs tag. I will not do that in the future. Thanks for your answer and comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the options for [`MoleculeGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeGraph.html) and you will see:

```
In[39]:= Options[MoleculeGraph, IncludeHydrogens]

Out[39]= {IncludeHydrogens -> All}
```

I believe this explains the discrepancy

Comment: Could this be documented? I looked at `Options[MoleculeGraph]`, but after it output all standard graph options, I gave up on trying to see if there's anything else.

Comment: You are right that is definitely an omission on my part.